# solution for popup page as modal

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, thickbox

I was using window.showModalDialog() but doesn't work on all browsers.

People recommends me jquery, [thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) and also this [contact Example](http://www.ericmmartin.com/simplemodal/)

but the problem is when i submit the page, server will send me another page, and that page will replace my original page!

so actually it doesn't fulfill my requirement.
My requirement is on button click modal page should open and it can redirect to other page on same window without disturbing  my original page and when I close My original page get reflections.
So is it possible?

Comment: Popup blockers are very common, they may have to do with the code not working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a simple html target="_blank" in the link to the other page.

http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linking/_A_TARGET_95y98y108y97y110y107y.html